# fs.readdir inside ipcMain.handle does not return

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, readfile, ipcmain

it always returns undefined, any idea please?
i need the return inside  fs.reddir but relative to ipcMain

```
//main

ipcMain.handle('pegaDirRomSalvo', async (event, argx=0) => {
  fs.readFile('dataCR.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

    if (err) {return '0'}
    fs.readdir(data, (err, files) => {
          if (err) {throw err;}
          return [data,files] //<-------- not going
    })
   
  })
})


//render

ipcRenderer.invoke('pegaDirRomSalvo',a=0).then((result)=>{
         document.getElementById('divCaminho').innerText = result[0]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `event.sender.send` to trigger another call from the `main` to the `renderer` process to return the result, where the last will listen to it using `ipcRenderer.on`. Here is a sample solution:

**renderer:**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.invoke('pegaDirRomSalvo', a=0);
ipcRenderer.on('FILES_LIST_FETCHED', (event, result) => {
     console.log(result);
     document.getElementById('divCaminho').innerText = result[0]
});
```

**main:**

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
ipcMain.handle('pegaDirRomSalvo', async (event, argx=0) => {
     fs.readFile('dataCR.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
          if (err) { return '0'; }
          fs.readdir(data, (err, files) => {
               if (err) {throw err;}
               event.sender.send('FILES_LIST_FETCHED', [data, files]);
          })
     });
});
```

You can do the same for returning the error details if you want.

EDIT: This technique is usually used when sending the `renderer` call using `ipcRenderer.send` and receiving it on the `main` process using `ipcMain.on`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`ipcMain.handle(channel, listener)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) docs:

> If listener returns a Promise, the eventual result of the promise will be returned as a reply to the remote caller. Otherwise, the return value of the listener will be used as the value of the reply.

```js
// main
ipcMain.handle("pegaDirRomSalvo", (event, argx = 0) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile("dataCR.txt", "utf8", function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      fs.readdir(data, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve([data, files]);
      });
    });
  });
});

// render
ipcRenderer.invoke("pegaDirRomSalvo", (a = 0)).then((result) => {
  document.getElementById("divCaminho").innerText = result[0];
});
```

The code can be refactored using `async/await` and `fs.promises` to be much more readable

```js
// main
const fsPromisified = require("fs/promises");

ipcMain.handle("pegaDirRomSalvo", async () => {
  const data = await fsPromisified.readFile("dataCR.txt", "utf-8");
  const files = await fsPromisified.readdir(data);
  return [data, files];
});

// render
(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke("pegaDirRomSalvo");
    document.getElementById("divCaminho").innerText = result[0];
  } catch (err) {
    // handle errors
  }
})();
```

Or you can handle errors in the main process

Answer (score 1):

for anyone looking at this in the future:

Was just having the same issue, and i don't have "access" to `ipcRenderer` in my renderer scripts. However, using a preload script, the key is to return the "promised result" from your `ipcRenderer.invoke` in your `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` api:

```
// preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("renderer", {
  pegaDirRomSalvo: async (argx) => { 
    return ipcRenderer.invoke('pegaDirRomSalvo',a=0)
      .then((result)=>{
        return result;
      }
    )
  }
});
```

now you can create the function in the main file

```
//main.js
ipcMain.handle('pegaDirRomSalvo', async (event, argx=0) => {
  fs.readFile('dataCR.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {return '0'}
    fs.readdir(data, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {throw err;}
      return [data,files]
    })
  })
})
```

and calling this in renderer (i.e., `const val = window.renderer.pegaDirRomSalvo(1)`) will (well, SHOULD) return the contents of `[data,files]`